# How to resolve citations within an org-mode file?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

When writing scientific papers within `org-mode`, the usual way to go is to specify citations, e.g., with the help of `org-ref` and then to export the whole thing to LaTeX/PDF, which does also resolve the citations based on a BibTeX database.

While this works out very well in everyday work, I would be curious to learn whether it is also possible to stay within `org-mode` proper, hence to have all the references **automatically** resolved and printed at the end of the `org-mode` file.

This would have two nice consequences that I miss so far:

1. The export to HTML would also include resolved references.
2. Similarly, the export with `ox-reveal` (for outputting slides) would include them too.

**EDIT:**

It turned out that the desired consequences are actually not so difficult to achieve. Using `org-ref`, don't forget (as I did) to make use of `bibliography:your-bib-file.bib` and `bibliographystyle:your-bst-file.bst`.

Yet the underlying question about self-contained org-mode files still remains.

Comment: Export to HTML should automatically resolve all the citations.

Comment: @JohnKitchin That's true, indeed. I had forgotten to put `bibliography:` and `bibliographystyle:` in my org-mode file, using `#+bibliography` instead. However, exporting to HTML does not resolve keys so far. For instance, `cite:Chomsky:13` is exported as `Chomsky:13`.

Comment: That is what it is supposed to do. I assume you want something like numbers. See http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2015/12/03/Exporting-numbered-citations-in-html-with-unsorted-numbered-bibliography/ for one way to get something like that.

Answer (score 4):

You could try exporting via [ox-pandoc](https://github.com/kawabata/ox-pandoc) (requires [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/installing.html), which you could also use directly).  This will expand your citations, allows you to choose the citation style, and can export to many formats, including revealjs.  An additional benefit is support for an alternative citation syntax `[prefix @citekey postfix]` which might be more suitable for people in the humanities. The downside is that some advanced org-mode features may not be supported.

Comment: This only answers the peripheral issue of exporting the file. But thanks for pointing to `ox-pandoc`which I wasn't aware of.